# Django Rest Framework cannot access foreign key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a product which contains a foreign key yet when sending some JSON it doesn't work.

My models :

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    objects =  CategoryManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model) :
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price=models.IntegerField(default=0,blank= True, null=True)    
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True, null=True)
```

The serializers:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :

   class Meta :
       model = Category

       fields = ['name']


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :

   category = CategorySerializer(many= True)


   class Meta :

       model = Product

       fields = ['name','price', 'category']
```

The JSON I send (for ex.):

```
{
    "name": "HelloThere",
    "price": 30,
    "category": {
        "name": "GeneralKenobi"
    }
}
```

the view :

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def productcreate(request):
    serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid() :
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

When posting the data as it is, I create a product which has a name and a price but category doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaOdf.jpg)

Comment: Since writable nested serializers are not trivial to generalize you need to implement the create/update logic for any nested writable serializers yourself as outlined in the docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: what do you get in product ? product id? or error?

Comment: @ daneil James: well it creates the product, there is just no category assigned to it, I will edit the post to display the picture of what I get

Comment: @azundo just did but same result, product is created but category is not assigned

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you added to the serializers to handle writing the related fields?

Comment: One thought, since it's a many to many I would expect `category: [{name: "GeneralKenobi"}]` since there can be many categories per product, not just one.